# Spawning threads and stopping them

Tags: python, multithreading

I've been reading about threads for a couple of hours now and I'm doing something that others are not.  Most are implementing a thread and trying to get the thread to stop.  Instead, as you can see, the class below spawns the requested count of threads which calls the given function.  This will allow callers to write a function to say create records in a database and they have N users performing the test.  I don't want to ask my users to create the threads themselves.  The issue that I'm having is stopping the users threads since they will be writing code that will stay inside of while loops creating the records.  How do I kill there threads?  The t.kill_received = True worked for another test of mine but doesn't seam to be working for this new case.  This is not production code.

```
class FMpuThread( ):
    def __init__( self,threadCount, function, results ):
        self.count      = threadCount
        self.func       = function
        self.results    = results
        print 'count: ' + str( self.count ) + ' func: ' + str( function )

    def DoTest( self ):
        threads = []

        # Create correct thread count
        for threadId in range(self.count):
            print 'Starting thread: ' + str(self.func.__name__) + '(' + str( threadId ) + ')'
            t = Thread(target=self.func, args=( threadId, self.results ))
            threads.append( t )
            t.mStop = False
            t.start( )
            ti.Sleep(.2)        # wait to start next thread

        while len(threads) > 0:
            try:    # Join threads with timeout(don't block)
                threads = [t.join(1000) for t in threads if t is not None and t.isAlive()]
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print 'Cancelling all threads.  Could take a few seconds.'
                for t in threads:
                    t.mStop = True
                sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: What is `t.kill_received` ? Am I out of date on the threading interface?

Comment: You can't kill threads. Two options are to know that the thread is using some resource that you can close (causing it to wake in error and exit) or to poll some flag in its own loop to decide to exit. If doing the latter, you have to put that flag in some agreed to place.

Comment: It's from another post I found last year.  It compiles without issue.  It has been working and no longer works in this new environment.  The function that this is called with will have a loop.  Is there any way to get rid of it.  Politely if we must :)

Comment: Okay, it sounds like it was polling the flag. If you do `t.kill_received = False` before starting the thread and if the loop inside the thread checks `if threading.current_thread().kill_received"` then it should stop the thread the next time it goes around the loop.

Comment: The old code didn't check the flag... So it appears that everybody writing a function to be called by FMpuThread will need to write 2 lines ct = threading.current_thread() at the start of there function and in the while loop do something like while true or ct.kill_received = False.  I'll give this a shot.

Comment: Oooh... while ct.kill_received == False

Comment: Yes, except `== False`

Comment: Updated original code with tDelaney's suggested fix.  Example in answer below

Answer (score 0):

This is the implementation of tdelaney's idea!  Thanks!!

OK, this is the basic idea.  You want to have another class run x number of threads and you want them to all perform the same action.  You create a function to call.  That function performs the actions that you want.  This function might have a while loop in it that the thread spawner class wants to control if somebody types in Ctrl-C.  You get the current thread and ask if the thread should continue.  mStop is set to True when the spawner wants to stop.

```
def someFunc( threadID, results ):  
      ct  = threading.currentThread()

      while ct.mStop == False:
        # Do something here
        # Pause( 5 )
        # print 'Thread: ' + str( threadID )

    results[threadID] = totalRecieved


clientCount = 5
results = [None] * clientCount  # initalize entire array
fmThread = FMpuThread( rest, clientCount, tThreadBurner, results )
```

You will need to initialize the results with the requested thread count otherwise you will get asserts after you Ctrl-C.

Enjoy!!